# I modified GTK source code and recompiled: No effect

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, gtk, gnome

In Ubuntu (Gnome) there is absolutely no way the change the mouse wheel scroll rate for GTK applications. It is hard-coded in GTK and determined by a "smart" algorithm which dynamically depends on the window size.

So I downloaded the source and found the function that returns the step value. I changed it to return a very small number first, and then 0 (to see if it has any affect at all).

I did

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

as instructed by GTK website.

It compiles with no problems (I have the libraries)

Bu then, I restart and it has absolutely no affect. My guess is Ubuntu is still using the original GTK it shipped with. What do you think is wrong here?

Comment: On Ubuntu, you need to download the package source, modify that, and install your modified package. You *could* get make install the overwrite the package version, but you really shouldn't. Hopefully make install put it somewhere easy for you to clean up.

Comment: What do you mean by "package source"? Is what I downloaded from GTK website not the package source? And if I shouldn't overwrite it with make install, what else I am supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the GTK libraries used by Ubuntu are under `/usr/lib` but the one you did build and installed are under `/usr/local/lib` (because the implicit `--prefix` to `configure` is `/usr/local` not `/usr`).

Probably, by setting your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to look into `/usr/local/lib` before `/usr/lib` should help.

Comment: I see. So you're saying rather than replacing the one in /usr/lib, this would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: The correct way is to build an Ubuntu package appropriately and submit a patch upstream to the Gtk community. But you could just test your thing by setting your LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that Ubuntu (by way of Debian) *has* specific tools for this, for example:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libgtk-3-0
```

will install everything you need to build `libgtk-3.0`, while:

```
apt-get source libgtk-3-0
```

will get you the source code you need. You can patch it how you like, and then build `.deb` files containing your patches that are otherwise (from your patches I mean) indistinguishable from the Ubuntu version using:

```
debuild
```

Happy hacking!

Comment: So this will automatically overwrite the original GTK packages Ubuntu shipped with?

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. The OP wanted to know why `make install` wasn't supplanting the packaged GTK.

Comment: @ErenTantekin - That's exactly right.  If you want to revert, simply `apt-get --reinstall install libgtk-3.0`

Answer (score 1):

- [Shared Libraries](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)
- [ldd - print shared library dependencie](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ldd)

Manipulation of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and/or placing the necessary library files in the correct folders will get your modified files loaded.

Also note the use of `ldd` will enable you to verify that your modified libraries will be loaded. Here's a sample showing what will be loaded if I invoke `ls` on my current machine:

```
matt@stanley:~/src/pydlnadms$ ldd `which ls`
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7cdde000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f245e288000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f245e080000)
    libacl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1 (0x00007f245de77000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f245dae3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f245d8df000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f245e4ca000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f245d6c0000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f245d4bb000)
```

Install your modified GTK+ shared libraries, manipulate the environment correctly, and then verify with `ldd` that your changes will be active.